# Best way to maintain a collection of created objects

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I want to maintain a collection of created objects of a Klass. I have two methods im mind:

First: Thru `initialize`:

```
class Klass
  @@objs = []

  def initialize *args
    # ... do regular initialization ...
    Klass.send :add, self
  end

  class << self
    def objs
      @@objs
    end

    private

    def add obj
      @@objs << obj
    end
  end
end
```

Second: Thru `new`:

```
class Klass
  @@objs = []

  class << self
    def objs
      @@objs
    end

    alias_method :old_new, :new    # never thought someday I'd name something as "old_new"!
    private :old_new

    def new *args
      obj = super
      @@objs << obj
      obj
    end
  end
end
```

Testing:

```
a = Klass.new
b = Klass.new
puts a.inspect            #=> #<Klass:0xb7786ba0>
puts b.inspect            #=> #<Klass:0xb7786b78>
puts Klass.objs.inspect   #=> [#<Klass:0xb7786ba0>, #<Klass:0xb7786b78>]
```

Both works, and I tend to prefer the second way, because of "add": it must be private, and I must use "Klass.send". What is the best way? Is there some other (better) manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you simply just `<<` in the normal constructor? Simple code and you don't have to redefine `new` which is rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

Sine initialize is called every time a new object is created, I would take advantage of this fact and just do:

```
def initialize *args
    # ... do regular initialization ...
    @@objs << self
end
```

Comment: Jakub said essentially the same. Thank you anyway! :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that your `alias_method` and `private` were not needed, as the `new` you normally call is `Class#new`. Also, there's no reason to use a class variable (unless you are trying to track sub-class creations on the master class). This works just as well, if not better:

```
class Foo
  class << self; attr_reader :objs; end
  def self.new(*a,&b)
    super.tap{|o| (@objs||=[]) << o}
  end
end
class Bar < Foo; end
2.times{ Foo.new }
3.times{ Bar.new }

p Foo.objs
#=> [#<Foo:0x2bb6260>, #<Foo:0x2ba2400>]

p Bar.objs
#=> [#<Bar:0x2ce6000>, #<Bar:0x2baf4e0>, #<Bar:0x2b94f40>]
```

The benefit of this technique over appending to the array in your initializer is that you don't need to remember to call `super` in the `initialize` of your subclasses. Indeed, you don't need to even *define* an `initialize` in your subclasses.

Comment: +1 for opening my eyes about `Class#new` and for using `tap` (great! if I knew `tap` before, I'd use it in my second example). But the `<<` in `initialize` (and the use of class variables) is what I was looking for. I know about class instances variables and them advantages over class variables, but in this case I'll use class variables.

Comment: @SonySantos No problem, and I'm glad you have an answer you were looking for. I added this answer (seeing that you had already accepted an answer) not because I was trying to sway you to switch to my answer, but only so that other users with slightly different needs finding this question have another answer to consider. Happy Ruby coding! :)

Comment: I realized that my original intention was to do `obj = old_new *args` instead of `obj = super` in my second example. I don't know why that worked. If I call `super` from inside an instance method, it will send a message of a parent class of current object - ie, `object.class.superclass` - to execute an instance method with the same name. If I call `super` from a class method, I guess it will send a message of a parent class of current class as an instance, ie, `Klass.class.superclass`, which is `Module`, which hasn't `new` as instance method.

Comment: @SonySantos See my [Ruby Method Lookup Flow](http://phrogz.net/RubyLibs/RubyMethodLookupFlow.png); class methods of a class inherit from class methods of a `Object`, which inherit from instance methods of `Class`, which is where `Class#new` is defined. (And from there they inherit from instance methods of `Module`, then instance methods of `Object` and finally to `Kernel` mixed into Object. (And in Ruby 1.9 there's a step to `BasicObject`, not present in the diagram.)

Answer (score 0):

You could also do

```
class IndividualKlass
end

class KlassCreator
  def initialize(individual_klass)
    @individual_klass = individual_klass
    @objects = []
  end

  def create_object
    object = @individual_klass.new
    @objects << object
    object
  end
end

klass_creator = KlassCreator.new(IndividualKlass)
IndividualKlass = nil # Or remove_const or something

object = klass_creator.create_object
```